# Copy files using FTP in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to copy file(s) using webrequest inside WCF. I need some suggestions. Are there better ways of doing this?

What kind of security issues am I going to face here?

Can I do it inside WCF or is making it separate better?

```
public void InsertOccured(string Name)
{
  //  Console.WriteLine("Insert Occured",Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Insert Occured, {0}", Name);
   // FTP request to download the file from FTP Location
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;

    try
    {
        string FilePath;
        string FileName = Name;

        //use Switch statement to identify the ftpServerIP

        FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(FilePath + "\\" + FileName, FileMode.Create);
        reqFTP= (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpserverIp + FileName));
        reqFTP.Method= WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
        Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        long cl = response.ContentLength;
        int bufferSize = 2048;
        int readCount;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (readCount > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        ftpStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
        response.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The streams and the response objects all should be in `using` blocks.

Comment: Not necessarily enough to put in to a full answer but I found when I wrote my own version of exactly what you are doing using a much larger buffer size helped a lot.

Comment: @Lloyd, what am trying to achieve here is ,my CLR trigger pass the File Name and Location of the file send to WCF,my FTPWebreqest get those information copy the file from the destination location to Local.

Comment: I haven't test it yet but one thing am sure am trying to copy the big files (video files) from Destination to Local .

Comment: @JohnSaunders am using DotNetUser code ,he use "Using" in his code.

Comment: I meant `using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(FilePath + "\\" + FileName, FileMode.Create)) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always better to make it separate but I don't know much about security issues with WCF however you could use this code to read responseStream, you should be using "using" to have framework manage disposing the stream properly

```
    try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4155]; 
            byte[] newBuffer;
            int readSize = 0;
            FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(FilePath + "\\" + FileName, FileMode.Create);
            int i = 0;
            using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                    readSize = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (readSize > 0)
                    {
                        newBuffer = new byte[readSize];
                        Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, readSize);
                        outputStream.Write(newBuffer.ToArray(), 0, readSize);
                    }
                outputStream.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks All for your valuable Input

Comment: thanks for your code,i was trying to use your code. newBuffer doesn't show the properties for ToArray().(newBuffer.ToArray()).It throws exception "System.Array" doesn't contain definition for "ToArray.Do i miss some thing here

Comment: you can use it without converting calling ToArray() as well, ideally it should not give error if newBuffer is of type byte[]. Let me know if u stil prblm with it.

Comment: ,am still have problem with .ToArray(),i was trying to find out why even though i change the code like outputStream.Write(newbuffer, 0, readCount); this works fine but i was trying to replicate by your code always throws exception.

Answer (score 4):

Using FTP is not the most secure. Username, passwords, and all data are sent in the clear. If you are concerned about security you should consider using SFTP.

Comment: @Scott,that's what my concern too, but have to go with Ben Voigt idea.